# How much of a factor is slug size on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, middleman

Planning to make a site with static html content, I explored alternatives to using Rails on Heroku since I didn't need a database or any of the other features offered by Rails. I heard Middleman static site generator might help me create a lightweight site that I could deploy to Heroku.

I made a test site with Middleman with about 6 mostly empty pages of html content (basically just a title on each page). After pushing to Heroku, I got these stats for repo and slug size

```
Repo size: 7.33 MB
Slug size: 8.3 MB of 200 MB
```

The slug size  is larger than the repo size. According to the Heroku docs,  slug is supposed to be " compressed and pre-packaged copies of your application optimized for lightning-fast distribution across the dyno manifold." I'm guessing slug size should be smaller than a repo size.

For the sake of comparison, I looked at the stats for a basic Rails app of mine, which I just use as a blogging engine (with Enki). It has a database and about 50 blog posts currently.

```
Repo size: 17.2 MB
Slug size: 5.55 MB of 200 MB
```

So, while the repo size of the Rails app is much larger, the slug size is smaller.

Is slug size the only factor affecting performance on Heroku? If so, would the obvious choice for me be to go back to using a simple Rails site even though I'm really only planning on posting a little bit of static content?

Leaving aside the slug size, would you imagine that the middleman site might still be faster since it's not using a database? and therefore doesn't have to make a query to retrieve content? With the middleman site, I'll just be writing the content directly into the html pages.  My real concern for the site is to let the users move quickly between the content pages. With the smaller-slug sized Rails app, that'd involve a database query, whereas with the larger slug-sized Middleman app, it won't.

Comment: consider http://pages.github.com/ for static html site

Comment: @house9 thanks for the recommendation. Can you comment on the performance vs. on heroku? For example, heroku offers one free dyno. One request handled at a time etc, which can create problems if you get spikes in traffic etc.

Comment: my guess is it will be far superior to heroku for serving static content, heroku is not designed for serving static content

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is slug size the only factor affecting performance on Heroku?

The slug size doesn't affect your app's performance. If your slug is smaller your deploys will be faster, but once the app is deployed the performance will only depend on its code and the resources it uses.

You mentioned a good example: a typical Rails app will probably make several queries to a database and therefore take longer to respond than a typical middleman app, which just reads and returns HTML.

Comment: remember if you're dynamically scaling your site, then the slug size will impact how quickly you scale, as it impacts time to spin up a new engine